# Ng change in directive is too slow ? why

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

Hi I am facing a hard time trying to findout why my directive is calling the ngChange function so slow. Without template it works super fast.

Here is my Html **Directive Template**

```
  <input type="search" class="search_input artist-job-search-input"
                       placeholder="Search jobs by profession, musical work, role or institution"
                       ng-model="$ctrl.artistSearchModel"
                       ng-change="$ctrl.searchArtistJob()"
                       ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}" select-on-click
                       style="max-width: 55.9vw;"/>
```

Here is **directive.js**

```
app.directive('jobsSearch', function () {

return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
        'artistSearchModel': "=",
        'showDropdown': "=",
        'operaticRoleSearchResult': "=",
        'viewAllJobs': "&",
        'musicalWorkSearchResult': "=",
        'institutionSearchResult': "=",
        'changeTypeOfFilter': "&",
        // 'searchFilterOne': "=",
        // 'searchFilterTwo': "=",
        // 'searchFilterThree': "=",
        // 'searchFilterFour': "=",
        // 'searchFilterFive': "=",
        'searchArtistJob': "&",
        'placeOfSearch':"@placeOfSearch",
        'artistFilterSearch':'='
        },
    controller: function () { },
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
    bindToController: true,
    templateUrl: '/views/profile/directives/job_search.html'
};
```

});

And this is where I am calling the directive `Directive call`

```
<jobs-search artist-search-model="jobDashboard.artistSearchModel" 
          search-artist-job="jobDashboard.searchArtistJob()"
          show-dropdown="jobDashboard.showDropdown"
          operatic-role-Search-result="jobDashboard.operaticRoleSearchResult"
          view-all-jobs="jobDashboard.viewAllJobs(paramsJobs)"
          musical-work-search-result="jobDashboard.musicalWorkSearchResult"
          institution-search-result="jobDashboard.institutionSearchResult"
          change-type-of-filter="jobDashboard.changeArtistJobFilter(params)"
          place-of-search="Jobs"
          artist-filter-search="jobDashboard.artistFilter"
```

> 

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}"
```

Tells angular to not recognize the change until 500 milliseconds have gone by after finishing typing. Is this the dealy you're referring to?

Comment: no no, i checked the inspect element and the call does not go.